# Nativescript ios: CLI stalling. Error: "Too Many sources"

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-cli

I am using a recently installed nativescript3. I am trying to run a simple app on the simulator (or anywhere I can view it). I have been running $ tns run ios. This has sometimes opened the app successfully in a simulator before, but now its not working.

Without changes in the code, it is now stalling. What can I do?

Here is the relevant output in the terminal:

```
Project successfully built.
Installing...
Successfully installed on device with identifier '[XXXXX-XXXX...]'.
Unable to apply changes on device: '[XXXXX-XXXX...]'. Error is: cp: dest is not a directory (too many sources).
Executing after-watch hook from /Users/.../expNSApp/hooks/after-watch/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
```

And it stalls there. No further action, and if I click on the app in the simulator it says "Unable to Install "[APP]". Please try again later."

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it a coincidence that only a few hours before your posting here I asked on NativeScript's Slack about my `tns run android` hanging? Are you using a local dependency?

Comment: The project is very simple right now, so I would be surprised if there is a dependency issue. I have not downloaded any new plugins or dependencies.

Comment: Note that when I start up the terminal after a break, running $ tns run ios gives me this error: "Unable to find applicable devices to execute operation. Ensure connected devices are trusted and try again". Simply retrying $ tns run ios gets rid of this error, but then has the problem described above--the build stalls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it looks like the problem was some code in App_Resources/ios/info.plist. I had made some changes in there, and when I return it to its original state, the app is able to load.  So I expect that the stalling issue happened because there is some fundamental code, somewhere, that is off--meaning the error arose more from the code base than from the CLI. There were no error messages pointing to that file.

I still have the issue that when I first start the app, I get an error: "Unable to find applicable devices to execute operation. Ensure connected devices are trusted and try again". The error goes away when I run $ tns run ios again, but that doesn't seem like an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the "stalling" is actually just the tns run command waiting for the next file change(s)...but if it failed to compile then sometimes this won't see any changes and you'll have to Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Z and try again.